# How to create dynamic refs in functional component- Using useRef Hook

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

I want to have refs in functional components which have elements dynamically rendered.

Please help me in creating Dynamic Refs using the `useRef` Hook and accessing it in the handler.

1. Need to create 3 `useRef`s to point to 3 buttons.
2. Access them in the button handler using "ref1.value" Or "ref2.value" etc.

````
let abc=[1,2,3];
function submitclick(){
    alert(123);
}

// Here I want to access the buttons using the refs
return ( <div>
  {  abc.map(function(index){ return (<button ref='123' onClick={submitclick}>{`Button${index}`}</button>)})}
    </div>);
};

ReactDOM.render(<MyComponent name="doug" />, document.getElementById('root'));```
````

Comment: What did you try? Do you read the docs?

Comment: why do you need `useRef` here in the first place?

Answer (score 90, accepted):

`ref`s are basically objects, and they have a default key `current`. So, you can create an array of `refs` like this:

```
const myRefs= useRef([]);
```

Then you can populate this array of refs like this:

```
ref={el => (myRefs.current[i] = el)}
```

---

Here is the full version:

```
{
  [1, 2, 3].map((v, i) => {
    return (
      <button
        ref={(el) => (myRefs.current[i] = el)}
        id={i}
        onClick={submitClick}
      >{`Button${i}`}</button>
    );
  });
}
```

Comment: for anyone wondering about the Typescript usage, simply add a `!`

- 

`ref={(el) => (myRefs.current[i] = el!)}`