# How can I iterate over an array and make a ref for each item with a functional-component the same way I'm doing it with a state-component

Tags: reactjs, react-redux, react-hooks

State-Component

```
props.dictionary.words.forEach((word) => {
    return this[word] = React.createRef()
  })
```

Trying to do something like this with a functional-component

```
props.dictionary.words.forEach((word) => {
    return word = createRef()
})
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to create dynamic refs in functional component- Using useRef Hook](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57810378/how-to-create-dynamic-refs-in-functional-component-using-useref-hook)

Comment: @CertainPerformance No, I don't understand certain parts of it. I don't understand what el is or how myRefs is being populated.

Comment: The `el` in that other answer is the argument passed to the ref prop function. It gets populated when the component renders.

Comment: In addition to the reference to the other question @CertainPerformance provided, [this deep dive article in the official documentation](https://react.dev/learn/manipulating-the-dom-with-refs#how-to-manage-a-list-of-refs-using-a-ref-callback) might clarify, although their example is slightly more complex.