# React functional component dynamic number of useRef

Tags: reactjs, use-effect, use-ref

I have functional component that only in run time I know how many useRef needed.
run time, in this case, means inside useEffect that depends on some parameters and only then I know how many useRef needed...
Of course, useRef / createRef can't be used in useEffect.

Examples I saw are about defining array in ref.current when component initially rendered.

What can I do?

Comment: `Examples I saw are about defining array in ref.current when component initially rendered.` That sounds like what i would do. Does that not work for some reason? You may need to give us more details about what you're trying to do with these refs.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to create dynamic refs in functional component- Using useRef Hook](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57810378/how-to-create-dynamic-refs-in-functional-component-using-useref-hook)